# How to get variables inside a RxJS subscribe() function?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working with angular2.
Now, I'm in trouble to get a value inside subscribe().
I know it will return null.
How can I return the correct value?

Here's my code. Anyone give me advice, it would be very helpful. Thank you :)

```js
this.deliveryService.deliveryCancel(rowInfo.branchId, rowInfo.id).subscribe(
              res => {
                var data = res.json();
                this.getDeliveryList();
                this.msgs.push({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Info', detail: rowInfo.deliveryStatus });
              },
              err => {
                this.errMessage = <any>err;
                this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: this.errMessage });
              }
            );
            
            console.log(data);
```

**deliveryCancel()**

```js
 deliveryCancel(branchId, deliveryId) {
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.http.put(this.testUrl + '/admin/branches/' + branchId + '/deliveries/' + deliveryId + '/cancel', {
      headers: headers
    })
      .catch(handleError);
  }
```

Comment: can you clarify your question and relate it to the code you posted?

Comment: Where is RXJS and where is subscribe method in your question ?

Comment: @shusson, I just edit my code. My bad :(

Comment: @rajm same, my bad

Comment: check out your deliveryCancel method.. That might return the null. Post that method here too.. Please try to elaborate your question

Comment: @rajm I want to use values the processed data in subscribe() outside of subscribe(). deliveryCancel mathod return correct value.

Comment: If it returns correct value then what value it returns.. Json or anything else ? How do you confirm it returns correctly.. ?

Comment: @rajm, It returns JSON data, but if I print it, it prints 'null'
I think I need to know about asynchronous call like what  @ echonax said.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access res.json() like that. And initialise 'data' as class variable. Try this.

```
data = {};

this.deliveryService.deliveryCancel(rowInfo.branchId, rowInfo.id).subscribe(
          res => {
            this.data = res['_body'];
            this.getDeliveryList();
            this.msgs.push({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Info', detail: rowInfo.deliveryStatus });
          },
          err => {
            this.errMessage = <any>err;
            this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: this.errMessage });
          }
        );

        console.log(data);
```

Comment: What do you think the result of `console.log(data)` will be?

Comment: @raj m, Thanks for your answer, It still prints null

Comment: console 'res' and let me know

Comment: @rajm, it makes an error that cannot find 'res'

Answer (score 0):

This is not an angular question but more a javascript question about asynchronous behaviour breaking flow of execution.

Suscribing means that on any error or success returned by deliveryCancel(), the res function or err function will be called.

Your console.log(data) is only executed once, and never part of those functions.

This is what you are after:

```
    this.deliveryService.deliveryCancel(rowInfo.branchId, rowInfo.id).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.data = res['_body'];
        this.getDeliveryList();
        this.msgs.push({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Info', detail: rowInfo.deliveryStatus });
console.log(data);
      },
      err => {
        this.errMessage = <any>err;
        this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: this.errMessage });
 console.log(data);
      }
    );
```

Comment: You will have to call deliveryCancel as well.

Comment: I personnaly subscribe to observables in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
However, it's not what I want to know.
I wanted to know how to use 'data' outside subscribe()

Comment: You said 'It returns JSON data, but if I print it, it prints 'null' ' in a comment, giving the impression that the call is successful. Console.log will let you know the outcome of your call. Please confirm it is an Object and not 'undefined'. Once this.data has been assigned you can simply access it in your template following [this method](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html), or in the component in any function/getter using this.data. I repeat, that will ONLY be available after subscribe instruction execution and after deliveryCancel has been called.